Pdfjs-dist won't work on next 14 app router (Javascript not TS)
I'm trying to extract text from pdf files made availabe to the browser via the input element, however for some reason, I get errors that don't seem directly related to my code, more like the library itself.
And this has happened with many pdf libraries, seems like a thing with next 14 and pdf libraries.
I have tried many methods but it seems pdfjs-dist just won't work with next.js (I'm using js btw not ts)
Here's my current code :
import * as pdfjs from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.mjs";

const pdfjsWorker = await import("pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs");
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker;

//select all pdf files for text extraction
const pdf_files = files.filter(async (file) => {
  if (file.type === "application/pdf") {
      // create blob from file in order to convert it to a url to be passed to pdfjs-dist
      const pdf_file_blob = new Blob([await file.arrayBuffer()], {
          type: "application/pdf",
      });

      const pdf_file_url = URL.createObjectURL(pdf_file_blob);

      const doc = await pdfjs.getDocument(pdf_file_url).promise;
      const num_pages = (await doc).numPages;

      let all_text = "";

      for (let i = 1; i <= num_pages; i++) {
          const page = await pdf.getPage(i);
          const content = await page.getTextContent();
          const text = content.items
              .map((item) => item.str)
              .join("");
          all_text += text;
      }

      return all_text;
  }
})

Next throws an error:
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid. Received a promise that resolves to: [object Promise]. Lazy element type must resolve to a class or function.
What can I possibly do to fix this error?

I faced the same issue. Make sure that your parent component is dynamically imported, with ssr: false param.
const ComponentC = dynamic(() => import('../components/C'), { ssr: false })

